# Use palette rendering style in SF symbol usage of tabItem

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios17

I'm trying to make my SF symbol display a two-tone color style (Palette) in SwiftUI tabItem - is this natively supported in SwiftUI or do I need to import UIKit?

```
.tabItem {
                Label("Library", systemImage: "book.circle")
                    
            }
```

[image: SF Symbol rendering mode]

I've tried appending .renderingMode(.template) to my Image but that doesn't appear to have worked

Answer (score 2):

SFSymbols use `.symbolRenderingMode` to specify the way they are coloured. Not `renderingMode`.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-get-custom-colors-and-transparency-with-sf-symbols